# Validation Control is not working under SandBox Solution

Tags: validation, sharepoint-2010

I am working on SandBox solution(SharePoint 2010). Below is my code

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class TestValidationControl : WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Label lblApplicationTitle = new Label();
        lblApplicationTitle.Text = "Application Title";
        this.Controls.Add(lblApplicationTitle);

        RequiredFieldValidator rfvApplicationTitle = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        rfvApplicationTitle.ControlToValidate = "txtApplicationTitle";
        rfvApplicationTitle.ErrorMessage = "*";
        rfvApplicationTitle.EnableClientScript = true;
        this.Controls.Add(rfvApplicationTitle);

        TextBox txtApplicationTitle = new TextBox();
        txtApplicationTitle.ID = "txtApplicationTitle";
        this.Controls.Add(txtApplicationTitle);

        Button btnSave = new Button();
        btnSave.Text = "Save";
        btnSave.CausesValidation = true;
        this.Controls.Add(btnSave);
    }
}
```

When I click on Save Button page gets post back. Page should not be postback if i am not entering under text box.

Comment: Did you try to create the textbox first and the requiredfieldvalidator second?

Comment: Let me give a try to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be using ValidationGroup property make it works fine

Comment: It is working but issue is, when i click on button it does postback. But let me give a try to your suggestion.